# Set Pentaho Spoon environment variables in a file

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I'd like to set database connections in a local Pentaho environment from a properties file so I can restart Spoon and keep the connection information. I'm sure there's some setting where I can do that, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `kettle.properties` file.

It is located in `$KETTLE_HOME/.kettle/kettle.properties`, which is by default: `~/.kettle/kettle.properties`

See also:

- https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.07+Variables
- https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Using+Variables+in+Kettle
- https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0L0/0Y0/030/050/020/000/010/010